# How can I make button gone in specific page of ViewPager?

Tags: android

My adapter

```
public class InitialViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private RelativeLayout mLayoutToInflate;
    private ArrayList<InitialModel> mInitialModelList;

    public InitialViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<InitialModel> mInitialModelList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mInitialModelList = mInitialModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_initial_activity_viewpager, container, false);
        mLayoutToInflate = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_to_inflated_initial);

        TextView title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_title);
        TextView descrition1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_above_image);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial);
        ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial_button);
        ImageView imageTitle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial_title);
        TextView textButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_button);
        TextView description2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_below_image);

        title.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTitle());
        imageTitle.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageTitle());
        descrition1.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmDescription1());
        image.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImage());
        if (mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTextButton() != null) {
            textButton.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTextButton());
        }
        if (mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageButton() != 0) {
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageButton());

        }
        description2.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmDescription2());
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

}
```

and in my MainActivity, I set

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position==0){
                    btnFunction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if(position==2){
                    btnFunction = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_initial);
                    btnFunction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(position==3){
                    btnFunction = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_initial);
                    btnFunction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if(position==4){
                    btnFunction = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_initial);
                    btnFunction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

What I want is to set the button dissapear on specific page of ViewPager but it make the button disappear on all pages.Please show me how to do that! Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Check](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a list of positions where you want to remove button and in `initializeView()` check for position and do whatever you want to do.

Have a look at following code and comment in that:

```
public class InitialViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private RelativeLayout mLayoutToInflate;
    private ArrayList<InitialModel> mInitialModelList;
    private ArrayList<Integer> pageListToRemoveBtn;     

    public InitialViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<InitialModel> mInitialModelList,ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mInitialModelList = mInitialModelList;
        this.pageListToRemoveBtn = list; // get page no where to remove button
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        return 5; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    } 


    @Override 
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    } 

    @Override 
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_initial_activity_viewpager, container, false);
        mLayoutToInflate = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_to_inflated_initial);

        TextView title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_title);
        TextView descrition1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_above_image);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial);
        ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial_button);
        ImageView imageTitle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial_title);
        TextView textButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_button);
        TextView description2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_initial_below_image);

        title.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTitle());
        imageTitle.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageTitle());
        descrition1.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmDescription1());
        image.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImage());
        if (mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTextButton() != null) {
            textButton.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmTextButton());
        } 
        if (mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageButton() != 0) {
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmImageButton());

        } 
        if(pageListToRemoveBtn.contains(positino))
        {
           // remove whatever view you want to remove.
         } 
            description2.setText(mInitialModelList.get(position).getmDescription2());
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    } 

}
```